# How to check with a value in comma separated values in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL problem. This is just an example just to solve my real problem. Let's say I have a table like this:

- Columns: id, name, classes.
- Classes field is comma separated value like 1,4,5,4

I know database design is wrong and very bad.

What I want to do is select `name` where class is equal to 4 whereas  the classes field has value 3,4,6,3,8 in MySQL. How can I do that?

Comment: `SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);`

Comment: @Wai where is the class field in your table I can see only id,name and classes

Comment: @aldrin27 `IN` wont work here as the column value is a substring. OP needs to use `LIKE` operator. I am not going to give the query, OP needs to research how to write query with `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function in MySQL

```
SELECT name 
FROM table_name
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('4',classes) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . This is perfect .

Answer (score 1):

use of find_in_set function like below-

```
select * from table_name where find_in_set('4',classes);
```